# Can I prevent std::sort from copying the passed comparison object

Tags: c++, stl

We're using a comparator object to sort a vector:

```
std::vector<Data> v = ....
Comparator c = ....
std::sort(v.begin(), v,end(), c);
```

However, this makes copies of c during the sorting, and is causing performance problems, because Comparator objects store a big map (in which lookups are done when calling the comparison function).
I thought I could force the use of references with:

```
const Comparator &ref = c;
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), ref);
```

but copies still happen with this.
Is there a way to prevent copies, or do I have to make the Comparator store only pointers to heavy data ? (I don't think we can use lambda/closures with our compiler version).

Comment: Can you use `std::ref`?

Comment: Don't make the comparator store values. Just make it have a reference to the map.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first thing to note is that the standard provides very little guarantees as of how many copies will be done for function objects.  If you need to use state-full functions you should use reference semantics (have the state pointed to by the functor, rather than held inside).

That being said, the first alternative is to refactor the functor or to wrap it:

```
struct Wrapper {
   Comparator *cmp;
   Wrapper(Comparator *cmp) : cmp(cmp) {}
   bool operator()(T const & lhs, T const & rhs) const {
      return (*cmp)(lhs,rhs);
   }
};
Comparator cmp(...);
Wrapper w(&cmp);
sort(v.begin(), v.end(), w);
```

This is actually the same you would be getting if you use `std::ref` (C++11) directly:

```
Comparator cmp(...);
sort(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ref(cmp));
```

Comment: I'd rather use std::ref, it's much less boilerplate :)
Why would implementations need to copy the comparator ? I'd say if you pass a reference, it could be just passed around from function to function.

Comment: `std::ref` is designed to solve exactly this problem.

Comment: Good answer, but makes me wonder why the standard does not specify that Compare objects are passed by constant reference rather than by value. Barring the very unlikely case that a comparer modifies its own state when called, I can hardly see any occasion where passing by reference would _not_ be desirable.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: You can always get reference semantics on an interface taking values by using something like `std::ref`, but you cannot get value semantics out of an interface taking a reference. I am not sure of the implications of a `const Cmp&` on the interface at the time that those interfaces were created when the argument is a function name (which decays to a pointer to function in the value case, in the reference case I am not sure if `const` could have issues)