# Passing object to compare function makes sorting slow?

Tags: c++, sorting

I had the following code in my program.

```
//Compare class
class SortByFutureVolume
{
public:
        SortByFutureVolume(const Graph& _g): g(_g){}

        bool operator() (const Index& lhs, const Index& rhs){
            return g.getNode(lhs).futureVolume() > g.getNode(rhs).futureVolume();
        }
    private:
        Graph g;
};
```

And then I use it for sorting like this:

```
    std::sort(nodes.begin(), nodes.end(),SortByFutureVolume(g));
```

When I run the above code on my mac computer for a vector of size 23K it completes in a fraction of seconds. However, when I run on my ubuntu 14 machine. It takes several minutes and it hasn't even completed yet.

I search for this problem and found the following solution here [Can I prevent std::sort from copying the passed comparison object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29695755/can-i-prevent-stdsort-from-copying-the-passed-comparison-object)

Basically modifying my code as so fixes the problem:

```
SortByFutureVolume s(g);
std::sort(_nodes.begin(), _nodes.begin()+ end, std::ref(s));
```

After this the runtime on both my mac an ubuntu are comparable. Very much faster.

I know that this works but I'm trying to understand why? I know that slow code above was due to copying of graph and SortByFutureVolume. Why do you need std::ref()? Is this solution even correct and is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Yes same level. However, on my mac using htop to visualize memory, I realized my mac used 4 cores for the sorting

Comment: @juanchopanza How is the graph copied if I'm passing by reference?

Comment: You have a flaw: The iterator of nodes is no iterator to a node, but some `Index`. Make an iterator able to dereference the desired node.

Comment: @unekwu It gets copied into `g`, `Graph g;`.

Comment: @DieterLücking I actually meant vector<Index>

Comment: It works with the const reference. Now I understand why. I'll accept both answers as soon as I'm able too. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you sure that this is the only difference? I agree with @juanchopanza, there shouldn't be a change in performance between your two implementations

Comment: @Nasser Yes I ran the exact same slow code with the same exact flags on both machines. Although my mac uses g++-5 and ubuntu machine uses gcc 4.8.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of having a `Graph` data member in `SortByFutureVolume` you should have a `Graph &` or `const Graph &` if `g` can be read only.  This way, anytime the `SortByFutureVolume` is copied the `Graph` is not copied.

```
class SortByFutureVolume
{
public:
        SortByFutureVolume(const Graph& _g): g(_g){}

        bool operator() (const Index& lhs, const Index& rhs){
            return g.getNode(lhs).futureVolume() > g.getNode(rhs).futureVolume();
        }
    private:
        Graph& g;
        // or
        const Graph& g;
};
```

As pointed out by [Benjamin Lindley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440119/benjamin-lindley) in the comments if You change `SortByFutureVolume` to store a pointer to the `Graph` instead of a refernece then `SortByFutureVolume` becomes copy assignable as pointers can be assigned but references cannot.  That would give you

```
class SortByFutureVolume
{
public:
        SortByFutureVolume(const Graph& _g): g(&_g){}

        bool operator() (const Index& lhs, const Index& rhs){
            return g->getNode(lhs).futureVolume() > g->getNode(rhs).futureVolume();
        }
    private:
        const Graph * g;
};
```

As a side not it is okay to have `_g` as a variable name in a function parameter as it does not start with a capital letter but it is a good habit to not use leading underscores.  This is doubly true in the global space where `_g` would be an invalid identifier as it is reserved for the implementation.

Comment: I would recommend a pointer. Doesn't make much sense for the object to be copy constructible, but not copy assignable.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, why? I know a lot of objects which are exactly that. Also having a pointer would prevent the sorter from using temporary object.

Comment: @SergeyA: Why would you want that? And no, it doesn't prevent temporaries. You would still take the object in to the constructor by reference, but then take its address in the initialization.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, not in this case, but I know of business logic objects where copy construction is straightforward, but assingment is convoluted (and not neccessary). In this case it is simply not neccessary. As for pointer - yes, you are correct.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I added an example of using a pointer.  It hadn't even crossed my mind that you would want the comparator to be copy assignable

Comment: @SergeyA: Well I simply don't like putting arbitrary restrictions on how my classes can be used, especially when lifting those restrictions is such a trivial thing to do. There is no reason to expect that a class like this can't be assigned to, so it should be able to be assigned to.

Comment: @NathanOliver Is there still any need to use std::ref after using any of the above fixes?

Comment: @unekwu It should not be needed as it makes the class act like a reference.

Answer (score 4):

`std::ref` is a pointer in disguise. What the code does is that instead of copying a heavy-weight `SortByFutureVolume` object, it copies around the pointer to the same object - which is obviously much faster.

The option would be to make the `Graph g` a (const) reference inside the sorter object.

Comment: But the graph object is still copied into the functor `s`.

Comment: @juanchopanza, likely this is not a big performance problem - judging by other evidence. I assume, `std::sort` implementation OP has does a copy of sorter on every iteration.

Comment: Makes sense. How is this done before c++11? I'm pretty new to the language.

Comment: Like i said - by having your `Graph g` as a (const) reference to the actual object inside the class.

Comment: That fixes it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your `SortByFutureVolume` was making a copy of whole graph each time it was being copied, and std::sort does a lot of copies by value of comparison function object.

see here:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49b9cdad8eb3bc06

for simple `std::vector<int>` sort it made internally 20 instantiations of `SortByFutureVolume` class. This same number of times your graph was probably copied.

`std::ref` copies only reference to your comparison function object - this removes all the deep copies and so also speeds up whole thing.

Answer (score 2):

The prototype for the std::sort variant you are calling is

```
template< class RandomIt, class Compare >
void sort( RandomIt first, RandomIt last, Compare comp );
```

(see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)

The compiler thus deduces that when you pass an unqualified `SortByFutureVolume(g)` you are passing by value. Constructing the temporary with your definition of `SortByFutureVolume` requires a deep copy of the graph. Potentially there is then a second copy made as the temporary is passed by value. If this parameter is passed by value within sort, further copies will be made.

When you use `std::ref()` the compiler can deduce that the third argument is a reference and so the pass becomes by reference, eliminating secondary copies of the graph.

As others have pointed out, the solution is to make member `g` a reference and make the constructor accept by reference.

```
class SortByFutureVolume {
    const Graph& g;

public:
    SortByFutureVolume(const Graph& g_) : g(g_) {}

    bool operator() (const Index& lhs, const Index& rhs){
        return g.getNode(lhs).futureVolume() > g.getNode(rhs).futureVolume();
    }
};
```

of course, if you have a C++11 compatible compiler, you could just use a lambda:

```
std::sort(nodes.begin(), nodes.end(), [&g](const Index& lhs, const Index& rhs) {
    return g.getNode(lhs).futureVolume() > g.getNode(rhs).futureVolume();
});
```